# Repartir dos Card en el total de una pantalla en React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Trabajo con React necesito poner en una porción de la pantalla una imagen y en el resto un login.

Deseo obtener lo siguiente
[image: login]

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente, es una aproximación

[image: login]

Se me ocurrio dividirlo con grid el de la izquierda en tamaño 8 y el de la derecha tamaño 4 muestro el código que ocupo.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Avatar, Button, Card, CardMedia, Container, Grid, Icon, TextField } from '@material-ui/core'
import LockOutlinedIcon from  '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined'
import CustomTypography from '../form/CustomTypography'
import useStyles from '../../theme/useStyles'
import imagen from './../../assets/images/gym/gimnasios-scaled.jpg'

const Login = () => {

    const classes = useStyles()
return (
    <Container className={ classes.containermt }> 
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={ 8 }>
                <Card>
                    <img src={ imagen } alt="hi" />
                </Card>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={ 4 } >
                <Card align="center">
                    <Avatar>
                        <Icon>
                            <LockOutlinedIcon />
                        </Icon>
                    </Avatar>
                    <CustomTypography >Login</CustomTypography>
                    <form className={ classes.form }>
                        <Grid item xs={ 12 } className={ classes.gridmb }>
                            <TextField 
                            label="Email"
                            variant="outlined"
                            fullWidth
                            type="email"
                            />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item xs={ 12 } className={ classes.gridmb }>
                            <TextField 
                            label="Password"
                            variant="outlined"
                            fullWidth
                            type="password"
                            />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item xs={ 12 } className={ classes.gridmb }>
                            <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            fullWidth
                            color="primary"
                            >
                                Ingresar
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </form>
                </Card>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Que necesito hacer para que quede como el ejemplo que estoy mostrando?

Comment: Seguramente el contenedor general esté con un max-width, deberás modificar el tamaño al 100% o 100vw y para la altura ponerle el 100vh (por ejemplo)

Comment: Ok, ya modifique `containermt: {
        marginTop: 30,
        maxWidth: '100%', 
        height: '100%'
    },`

Comment: @Zander Lo que falta es que la imagen quede en todo el card, como lo podría hacer?

Comment: La imagen puede ser un background image y usar `background-size: cover;`